# ActiveDocument error 4248 in Ribbon onLoad sub

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbonx

I have a global template with a customized ribbon. When I try to open a document, I receive error 4248, which claims the command can't run because no document is open.

The code in the onLoad sub is checking to make sure that the active document isn't the template or Normal.dotm because I don't want document variables written to those files via the called procedures. This worked fine in Word 2013, but I'm noticing that in Word 2016, it seems the ribbon onLoad procedure is running before a document in Word is open.
I've pinpointed the issue to the ActiveDocument.Name line, where I can trap the error and resume next, but that doesn't help me run the additional code after the determination is made that this isn't the global template document or Normal.dotm.

```
Public myRibbonNewNormal As IRibbonUI
Public bVisible As Boolean
Dim bDocSaved As Boolean

Sub onLoad_newNormal(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
Set myRibbonNewNormal = ribbon

On Error GoTo onLoadError

If ActiveDocument.Name = "Styles.dotm" Or ActiveDocument.Name = 
"newNormal.dotm" Then
  Exit Sub
ElseIf ActiveDocument.ReadOnly Then
  Exit Sub
Else
  'Call checkDocType
  Call uncheckUpdateStyles
  Call removeClientFooter
  Call checkTemplate
  If bDocSaved <> True Then
    Call preventSave
  Else
    'do nothing
  End If
End If

Exit Sub

onLoadError:
If Err.Number = 0 Then
  Resume Next
ElseIf Err.Number = 5 Then
  Resume Next
ElseIf Err.Number = 5825 Then
  Resume Next
ElseIf Err.Number = 5903 Then
  Resume Next
'ElseIf Err.Number = 5155 Then
'  Resume Next
ElseIf Err.Number = 4248 Then
  Resume Next
Else
MsgBox "This error is in the onLoad sub in the newNormal RibbonControl" _
  & vbCrLf & vbCfLf & "Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, , 
"Error"
End If

End Sub
```

(Please excuse my error handling. I was in a hurry when I wrote this code and just haven't gotten back around to doing it properly.)

Is there a way for me to wait to execute the onLoad sub until Word has opened the document (by simple double-click)? I'm sure I'm missing something here, but I'm struggling to find any information about this online.

Comment: Which line throws error? Without knowing details, dare to suggest to move code into separate procedure and use `Application.OnTime` which will call it after set time.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that more clear in my original question. The line that throws the error is the first ActiveDocument.Name If statement. If I move it into a separate procedure and call it from onLoad, I don't think that will help. The onLoad sub is called when the Ribbon is being initiated, which seems to be happening before the document is open in 2016 (but in 2013 it was happening after the document was open).

Comment: Try a loop that tests `If Documents.Count > 0` Once that's true, exit the loop and check the active document's name.

Comment: Thanks @Cindy. Unfortunately, I ended up with an infinite loop because 
    Documents.Count never got past 0 because the onLoad runs before a document is open.

Comment: Well, if it truly runs before a document is opened, and a document can't / won't be opened until it has run, the test is not possible. If a document *can* open while it's running you could try sticking a `Do Events` in the loop. Or you could try putting another label in the code so that you can `GoTo Label` in the error handler, back into the body of the `If`.

Comment: Thanks @Cindy. I added a Do Events to the loop when I tested it. The document doesn't open until the onLoad sub has finished completely, it seems, which means I'm going to have to figure out a new method to do many of the things that get done before the user is allowed to interact with the document.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to an application level event handler. The code will run each time a new document is opened, but that can be remedied if needed (see code comments).

**Create a new class module and name the class module EventMngr.**

**Place the following code in the class module:**

```
Public WithEvents appevent As Application

Private Sub appevent_DocumentOpen(ByVal Doc As Document)
    'This code will only allow the event to fire once
    Static hasOpened As Boolean
    If hasOpened Then Exit Sub Else hasOpened = True

    'Place Code Here...
End Sub
```

**Then you can place this line in a normal module before any other subs/functions**

```
'application level event handler
Public myEventHandler As New EventMngr
```

**And last, place this in your Ribbon OnLoad sub:**

```
'application event handler
 Set myEventHandler.appevent = Application
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately, this doesn't work because the Ribbon onLoad fires before the app event that fires when a document is opened. I tested this with simple message boxes. So, really, the issue is that the ribbon loads before a document loads in Word 2016, which is different behavior from Word 2013.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your answer initially and I'm 99% certain it will work. I'll mark this as the answer once I've tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer but possibly simpler is to add autoopen and autonew procedures to your code and capture the activedocument in those procedures rather than the onload procedure.

Comment: Will this work if I add these procedures to the global template? I thought these were only document level procedures.

Comment: They need to be in the Template on which the document is based or in the document itself.